# IntelliJ - completion suggestions order

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm wondering if there is a way to let IDE suggest methods before variables?
When writing code like this it's a pain to select methods yourself (builder class example)

Variable example:

`var message = "message"
        private set`

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it appears you can't reconfigure the IDE or Kotlin plugin in this way. You can file a feature suggestion for Kotlin plugin, but I believe there are cases when variables are preferred over same-named methods, so just reordering them would break someone else's habits, so it's tricky.

You can consider making the variables private (so they won't be shown in the completion list at all) or selecting them and then typing an opening parenthesis manually.

Comment: That‘s what i was afraid of :(